# Do I need to enable push notifications for my app id if I only use local notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Currently my app schedules a local notification for one week after the last time the app was run. Everything works fine in testing, but now that I've submitted the app I got this message from Apple:

"Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. "

I'm not actually interested in push notifications, I only want to use local notifications. Do I still need to enable Push Notifications for my App ID and recreate the provisioning profile?

Edit: The specific answer to my question is, no. You do not need to enable push notification for an app id in order to use local notifications.

Comment: did you fix that error by removing the lines mentioned by Rajan Balana, and then resubmitted? Or was the app approved anyway?

Comment: I too would like to know what the outcome was. I'm in a similar situation and not wanting to get an ssl certificate for a local notification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not interested in Push Notifications then please remove the following function from  App Delegate of your project and everything will be smooth :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{

}
```

and remove this code from applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions Function:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: Ah, I did play around with push notifications but I don't use them. So just having those functions in my code will trigger that message from Apple, even though I'm never calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes?

Comment: Yes it trigger this. Those methods get complied and thus are available when talking to the AppDelegate object. regards